# Moving local WAMP websites to Dropbox produces "404 Not Found"

Tags: dropbox, wamp

I have WAMP installed @ C:\wamp

I've moved the contents of C:\wamp\www to D:\Dropbox\WAMP\WWW

I've adjusted C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\Dropbox\WAMP\WWW\site"
    ServerName www.site.dev
    ServerAlias www.site.dev
    <Directory "D:\Dropbox\WAMP\WWW\site">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the system tray I've selected `WAMPserver icon > MySQL > my.ini`, and edited:

```
datadir=D:/Dropbox/WAMP/SQL/data
```

When I load www.site.dev, I receive the error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.6.18 OpenSSL/1.0.1r Server at www.site.dev Port 80
```

The security settings on `D:\Dropbox\WAMP\SQL` & `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data` are the same I believe (they both have System with full control).

Help appreciated.

Comment: Didi you restart everything? Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: @DavidPostill looks like I didn't restart everything, as restarting everything has resolved the problem. Add an answer if you like.

Comment: Answer added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### When I load www.site.dev, I receive the error

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.6.18 OpenSSL/1.0.1r Server at www.site.dev Port 80
```

Your configuration file changes look correct. Assuming there are no other errors in the error logs then the above error message suggests that Apache has not been restarted.

Restarting everything should resolve the issue.

If you still have problems then check the error logs again and update the question to include any errors.